# AJAX not giving me a responseText for 500 requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a function attached to the `error` on my ajax but it wont show me any error messages for 500 response codes? I display the error message with `xhr.responseText` but its returning an empty string, can anyone tell me why?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: "/ajax/account/create_key",
    data: { key_id: document.getElementById('account-key-value').value, expires_at: document.getElementById('account-key-expires').value },
    success: function(result) {
        // close modal

        swal({
            title: "That was a success!",
            text: 'Your account key has been created.',
            icon: "success",
            button: "Okay!",
        });

        document.getElementById('account-keys-content').innerHTML = result;
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
        if(xhr.status == 400) {
            swal({
                title: "Opps!",
                text: xhr.responseText,
                icon: "error",
                button: "Okay!",
            });
        }
        else {
            swal({
                title: "Opps, something went wrong!",
                text: xhr.responseText,
                icon: "error",
                button: "Okay!",
            });
        }
    }       
});
```

Comment: smells like internet explorer? :D

Comment: I'm using Chrome.